# While loop causes UI to go blank

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm writing a simple Whack a Mole clone, and I've got my UI elements declared in a GridLayout in a layout.xml, then assigned to ImageView variables in an array programmatically.  I've got a startGame() method that simply takes a random int, pulls it from the array and causes it to go visible for a second, then repeats.  For some reason, when I put this code in a while() loop, it causes my UI to go blank as soon as it's launched.

I know it's the while() loop because I tried taking the code out of the while() loop, and it ran correctly (once), but turns everything white when placed in a while loop.

Here's the method causing the problem:

```
public void startGame() {
    gameStarted = true;
    while(gameStarted) {
        randomInt = rand.nextInt(11);
        mole[randomInt].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mole[randomInt].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

All the other relevant code is in onCreate, it's otherwise just a skeleton Activity subclass.

```
public class WAM_Activity extends Activity {

    private ImageView[] mole = new ImageView[11];
    private int[] moleId = {R.id.mole1, R.id.mole3, R.id.mole4, R.id.mole5, R.id.mole6, R.id.mole7, R.id.mole8, R.id.mole9, R.id.mole10, R.id.mole11, R.id.mole12};
    private boolean gameStarted;
    private int randomInt = 0;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wam_view_layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            mole[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(moleId[i]);
            mole[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //do stuff eventually
                }
            });
        }
        gameStarted = true;
        startGame();

    }
```

Any idea why this isn't working?  I've been staring at it for hours and I'm quite stumped.

Comment: You can't just have an infinite loop, it doesn't give a chance for the UI to ever update.  Instead implement a timer with a call-back every 60th of a second or so.

Comment: Oh geez, I didn't even think of that!  What do you mean by a timer with a callback though?  Another user suggested starting a separate Thread, which I know how to do, but I'm curious about what you're talking about.  I'm going for the most simple solution, I'm writing this to teach my little cousin about programming.

Comment: Thread's is probably the right answer here.  Some languages / frameworks allow for a timer even that occurs ever so often, but I'm not sure android / java has anything native.  Was looking at how I wrote an old game on android a while back, it's just a while loop on a thread separate from the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't work that way, when `onCreate` is called, it need to be finished in order for the app to keep responding, I'm surprised you are not getting any "App not respopnding" error.

If you want to create a "game loop" you can simply by creating a new `Thread` and putting the while in there.

`Activity`'s lifecycle must be executed without blocking them for the app to operate correctly, for more info check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Do you know about threads? if you want i can post an example of how to do that with threads but it might be long and if you don't know what a `Thread` is it will be too confusing for you.

Edit: Ok I'll make an example of a `Thread`

When I create my games I usually have only one `Activity` that the only thing it does is creating a custom `SurfaceView` and nothing else.

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity
{
    //This is a custom class that extends SurfaceView - I will write it below
    private GameSurface game;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        //Create a new instance of the game
        game = new GameSurface(this);

        //Set the View of the game to the activity
        setContentView(game);
    }
}
```

You can also add extra stuff like `onSaveInstanceState` to save game data and restore them later but I don't want to add them now so the code looks simple.

This class was very simple, let's move on to our `SurfaceView`. The reason I picked a `SurfaceView` to do that it's because it is made to allow custom graphics to be drawn on it - exactly what we want on a video game. I will try to make the class as simple as possible:

```
/*SurfaceHolder.Callback will run some functions in our class when 
our surface is completed - at that point we can initialize data 
that have to do with the View's width/height.

I don't know if you've noticed that on a View's onCreate() 
when you call getWidth() or getHeight() you get 0, that's because 
the surface is not initialized yet, this is a way to fix that.

Also we need a Runnable to run the Thread inside this class, 
no need to make more classes and make it more complicated*/
public class GameSurface extends SurfaceView
    implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable
{
    //This is our thread - we need the "running" variable to be 
    //able to stop the Thread manually, this will go inside our "while" loop
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;

    //Right here you can add more variables that draw graphics
    //For example you can create a new class that has a function that
    //takes Canvas as a parameter and draws stuff into it, I will add
    //a Rect in this case which is a class already made by android 
    //but you can create your own class that draws images or more
    //complicated stuff
    private Rect myRect;

    //Rect needs a paint to give it color
    private Paint myPaint;

    //Constructor
    public GameSurface(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        //This is the callback to let us know when surface is completed
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    //When a class implements SurfaceHolder.Callback you are forced to
    //create three functions "surfaceCreated", "surfaceChanged" and 
    //"surfaceDestroyed" these are called when the surface is created,
    //when some settings are changed (like the orientation) and when 
    //it is about to be destroyed

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(Surface holder)
    {
        //Let's initialize our Rect, lets assume we want it to have 40
        //pixels height and fill the screen's width
        myRect = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), 40);

        //Give color to the rect
        myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setARGB(0, 255, 0, 0);

        //In case you are not familiar with the Rect class, as 
        //parameters it gets Rect(left, top, right, bottom)

        //Time to start our Thread - nothing much to explain here if 
        //you know how threads work, remember this class implements
        //Runnable so the Thread's constructor gets "this" as parameter
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    //We won't use this one for now, but we are forced to type it
    //Even if we leave it empty
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

    //When the surface is destroyed we just want the Thread to
    //terminate - we don't want threads running when our app is not visible!
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    //We will type this function later
    {destroyThread();}

    //Time for the interesting stuff! let's start with input
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        //The logic is as follows: when our Rect is touched, we want
        //it to become smaller
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            if (myRect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())
            {
                myRect.right -= 5;

                //Return true - we did something with the input
                return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    //This is our update, it will run once per frame
    private void update()
    {
        //Let's assume we want our rect to move 1 pixel downwards
        //on every frame
        myRect.offset(0, 1);
    }

    //Now for our draw function
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        //Here we want to draw a background and our rect
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 255);
        canvas.drawRect(myRect, myPaint);
    }

    //The only thing left is our run() function for the Thread
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //Screen
        Canvas canvas;

        //Our game cycle (the famous while)
        while(running)
        {
            //Count start time so we can calculate frames
            int startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            //Update our game
            update();

            //Empty screen so it can obtain new instance
            canvas = null;
            //Try locking the canvas for pixel editing on surface
            try
            {
                //Try getting screen
                canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();

                //Succeeded
                if (canvas != null) synchronized (getHolder())
                {
                    //Actual drawing - our draw function
                    draw(canvas);
                }
            } finally
            {
                //Draw changes
                if (canvas != null) getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

        //End Frame - 1000/30 means 30 frames per second
        int frameTime = System.currentTimeMillis() -startTime;
        if (frameTime < 1000/30)
            try { Thread.sleep(1000/30 -frameTime); } catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }

    //Last but not least, our function for closing the thread
    private void destroyThread()
    {
        //Stop thread's loop
        running = false;

        //Try to join thread with UI thread
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            try {thread.join(); retry = false;}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

I may have made some minor mistakes (probably with case sensitive letters) so feel free to correct these, I wrote the code at once so I didn't have time to test it, it should work flawlessly though.

If you have any more questions, need more explanation or something is not working right let me know!

Comment: Haha, makes perfect sense, I didn't even think of that.  I'm familiar with threads, thanks for the advice!

Comment: OK, I may have exaggerated my knowledge of how threads work in Java a little ():-) .  I'm having a lot of trouble finding a straightforward tutorial on this, and what I've got keeps crashing with no errors in logcat, so I'm making a logic error somewhere that I'm not seeing.  How would I go about encapsulating the while() loop I posted above into a new thread, and getting it to update the UI in the main thread?

Comment: @jamzsabb I edited my answer with more information, feel free to let me know if it helps you

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate it!  I saw a lot of tutorials using SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder, but since I'm using a layout.xml to do all my UI elements, all I need the thread to do is hide/show the moles at random intervals.  Am I going to have to re-write all of this to be drawn on a canvas?  All my relevant code is in the OP, I'm really trying to keep this simple as possible because I want to use it to show my little cousin about programming.  This is making MY head spin at the moment, though honestly I probably just need some time to mess with it and get my head around it.

Comment: Ok, that was kind of a long-winded question.  What I meant to ask was: can I use something like setContentView to load the layout.xml onto the SurfaceView subclass?  There's no setContentView() method in SurfaceView, so I'm thinking this answer is probably a no.....

Comment: You can create a `Thread` inside your `Activity`, make your `Activity` implement `Runnable` and apply a similar logic, but instead of obtaining the canvas try drawing your views inside the `Thread` like `view.invalidate()`, there may be an issue with drawing outside of your UI `Thread` so you need to use a handler, it's much simpler and much easier to implement but you don't have much control of the graphics, do you want me to write a full implementation ?

Comment: Would you say it's similar to this tutorial? http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Overview_of_Android_Threads_and_Thread_handlers
I'm just completely lost on how the thread communicates with the Activity and UI thread

Comment: So I took my while() loop from OP and added it to a Runnable.run() object method, then called a new Thread object with that as the argument and started it.  It works for a second and then crashes with no errors to logcat.  Feels like I'm getting closer though

Comment: I went ahead and just created another thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405343/having-trouble-communicating-between-threads, this has gone way beyond what my original question was about.  Thanks for all your help man, you're the reason amateurs like me are able to code and have fun!

Comment: @jamzsabb I was about to type a new answer here using a `Handler` and a `Thread` but as I've seen you've already done that, does this mean your problem is solved ?

Comment: Yep, got it figured out.  It wasn't nearly as complicated as all the tutorials I was finding made it out to be.  You just create a Runnable, pass it to a Thread, then create a Handler and pass Messages to the Handler using msg.obj and msg.what etc.  I don't know why I couldn't find a tutorial that would just explain that, I was able to piece it together from what you posted, what some other SO users posted, and tutorials I found.  Thanks again, I was really stuck for a while there!