# Having trouble communicating between threads

Tags: android, multithreading

My first attempt at both building a game and using multithreading is going mostly well, but I'm stuck at the moment.

It's a simple Whack a mole clone, so I've got a 3x4 grid of mole ImageViews declared in a layout.xml, then I'm using `setContentView(R.layout.layout)` to put it up, then a separate thread to make one of them appear for a second, then disappear.  Here's my Activity's `onCreate()`:

```
public class WAM_Activity extends Activity {

private static final int MAKE_VISIBLE = 1;
private static final int MAKE_INVISIBLE = 0;
private ImageView[] mole = new ImageView[11];
private ImageView currentMole;
private int[] moleId = {R.id.mole1, R.id.mole3, R.id.mole4, R.id.mole5, R.id.mole6, R.id.mole7, R.id.mole8, R.id.mole9, R.id.mole10, R.id.mole11, R.id.mole12};
private boolean running = true;
private int randomInt = 0;
private Random rand = new Random();
private Handler handler;
//private WAM_Thread wamthread = new WAM_Thread();
private Context cont = this;
private static Handler h;
Message msg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wam_view_layout);

    //add ImageViews declared in R.layout.wam_view_layout to ImageView objects
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        mole[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(moleId[i]);
        mole[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mole[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(cont, "You clicked one!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what) {
                case MAKE_VISIBLE:
                    currentMole = (ImageView) msg.obj;
                    currentMole.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case MAKE_INVISIBLE:
                    currentMole = (ImageView) msg.obj;
                    currentMole.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                randomInt = rand.nextInt(11);
                msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                msg.obj = mole[randomInt];
                msg.what = MAKE_VISIBLE;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                        msg.obj = mole[randomInt];
                        msg.what = MAKE_INVISIBLE;
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
}
```

All the moles are declared invisible by default in the layout xml file, so this code should be making one of them visible, wait a second, then make him invisible again and then make another visible and repeat.  Instead, it's making them all visible all the time.  They still respond to taps, but that's it.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I've been struggling with this since last night but I'm really close to getting it right.

Comment: In your main loop, `while (running)`, you're setting one mole to be visible and to disappear after a second, and then that loop immediately runs again and you set another mole to be visible, then again, and again, all in less than a second so they all become visible. Look at Buddy's answer for a start to fixing this problem (`Thread.sleep()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- at the end of your runnable, add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` so that the background thread pauses after making one thing visible
- inside your postDelayed runnable, you're not calling `handler.sendMessage`

Comment: Haha, that makes sense, thanks for the help that was exactly what I needed.  I took everything out of the postDelayed() and simply ran the part that made one visible, used the Thread.sleep() that you suggested, then made it invisible again.  Worked just like I expected!  Much thanks!